# How to use jupyter_client to get the execute result?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I'd like to use jupyter_client to execute some python code and get result. Here's my sample code. But I could not get the output `hello world`, Could anyone help me ? Thanks

```
import jupyter_client
kernel_manager, kernel_client = jupyter_client.manager.start_new_kernel(kernel_name='python3')
kernel_client.execute("print('hello world')")
kernel_client.get_shell_msg()
```